# Elasticsearch - Cardinality of Visitors group by day, But visitors be taken uniquely in the queried date range

Tags: elasticsearch, cardinality

We are trying to get the cardinality of visitors based on a time range, group by day. But the point to note is, the visitor should be taken unique in the complete queried date range
and then it should be grouped by day.

For example..
Our document samples,

```
   {visitorid:1,time:November 3rd 2016}
   {visitorid:2,time:November 3rd 2016}
   {visitorid:1,time:November 4th 2016}
   {visitorid:3,time:November 4th 2016}
```

Our result count (for the date range Nov 3 to Nov 4) should be like,

```
   Nov 3 - 2 visitors (visitorid 1,2)<br>
   Nov 4 - 1 visitors (visitorid 3, since visitorid 1 has already taken for Nov 3)
```

We have tried the following aggregation,

```
"aggs": {
    "articles_over_time": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "time",
        "interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "distinct_visitors": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "visitorid"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But it provides, the result as,

```
    Nov 3 - 2 visitors
    Nov 4 - 2 visitors
```

Since it does the group by first and then does the cardinality.

Please share us some solutions or alternative ideas to approach this.